# Receiving a Memory Address from a For Loop

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

Essentially, it seems that my data is being pulled from the db, but I receive the addresses instead of the strings themselves. What I am trying to get from the db is a list of 3 friends for a profile page, (stringproperties).

**This is my db class:**

```
class Friends(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    friend = db.StringProperty()
    added_date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

**My profile handler:**

```
class Profile(MainHandler):
    def get(self, profile_id):
        if self.user and profile_id:
            current_user = self.user.name
            name1 = ''
            friend_name = ''
            team_imagee = ''
            key = ''
            imgs  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Images WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            team_name  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teams WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            team_images  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teamimg WHERE user =:1", profile_id)
            friends  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Friends WHERE name =:1 order by added_date desc limit 10", profile_id)
            for clan in team_name:
                    name1 = clan.team_name_anycase
            for image in team_images:
                team_imagee = image.key()
            for img in imgs:
                key = img.key()
            self.render('profile.html', profile_id = profile_id,  current_user = current_user, friends = friends, team_img = team_imagee, team_name = name1, profile_image = key, username = self.user.name, email = self.user.email, firstname = self.user.first_name, last_name = self.user.last_name, country = self.user.country)
        else:
            self.redirect('/register')
```

**And the for loop in my template:**

```
{% for friend in friends %}
    {{friend}}
    <br>
{%  endfor %}
```

Would anyone be so kind as to tell me why I sometimes see these addresses instead of the objects themselves, (even just in general).

Comment: both answers below are correct, what do you expect to be shown if you are iterating over the whole entity? what you want is accessing a property of the object i guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view, you are returning the `db.GqlQuery("..")` query object that is an [iterator](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html) and you are actually printing the default object string representation of each entity returned by the query.

I guess you should have to iterate and access the `friend` property like this:

```
{% for friend_tmp in friends %}
    {{friend_tmp.friend}}
    <br>
{%  endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't defined any sort of default representation for your `Friend` class. So, Python will use the default object `__repr__` method, which usually shows the memory location.

Define a `__unicode__` method on the model which returns the string you actually want to show - it might be as simple as `return self.name`.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to use NDB, repr(friend) would be much more helpful.

Comment: Yes, I've been drinking up a sea of data from the docs. Eventually I will get around to streamlining my application. Oh and by the way, it is an honor. I feel the need to thank you for all you have done in the comp sci industry. Cheers!